# When I call "read_csv" I get an error stating DLL ‘vroom’ not found

Tags: r, readr

I am unable to use the read_csv function, even though I've used it in the past with no problems. I've re-installed the tidyverse, vroom, and readr packages, reset RStudio, and scoured a bunch of older, similar questions, but none seem to address the particular error message that appears.

I've confirmed and double checked that my working directory is where the file in question is located.

The error message made me think some packages were not installed, but even upon re-installing/loading the packages, the issue did not resolve.

Here is my code:

```
install.packages("vroom")  
install.packages("readr") 

library(tidyverse)  
library(vroom)  
library(readr)  
my_data = read_csv("my_file.csv")
```

My error message when I run this code:

```
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
DLL ‘vroom’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
```

If anyone can offer any solutions, it would be appreciated. Also, it is my first time asking a question here, so any feedback on question formatting is welcome.

Comment: Perhaps try `install.packages(c("vroom", "readr"), dependencies = TRUE)`.  Also the reference to `read.csv()` is an irrelevance - these are completely different functions - have edited to remove.

Comment: Thanks Ritchie, unfortunately that did not solve the issue. However, I logged into another account on my machine and did not have this issue, so it must be an issue with that account on my computer (running Win10)